# OpenMDAO installation

Tags: openmdao

I need openmdao on windows 8 to run an aerostructutal optimization code that uses it but I’m having issues in the installation process. I installed numpy and scipy through pip in the cmd and then also openmdao using pip install openmdao but when I try to run a .py with copied inside the code at the bottom of this page, I get an error about “Component” not being found to import. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: your question is a bit incomplete. Could you please include the full error msg and code you're trying to run? Also, could you more clearly list the steps you did to install things?

Comment: The error I get is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
** IDLE Internal Exception: 
  File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 353, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "C:\Users\Patrizio\Desktop\run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from openmdao.api import Group, Problem, Component, IndepVarComp
ImportError: cannot import name 'Component'

The code I'm trying to run is the one on this page of openmdao documentation (which I forgot to link before): 

http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.3/usr-guide/basics.html

Answer (score 1):

Some codes are written for a specific version of OpenMDAO. If you are using OpenAeroStruct, it requires OpenMDAO 1.7.4, not OpenMDAO 2.2.x.

To obtain the correct version, you would need to use the command `pip install openmdao==1.7.4` or to download and install the source directly from here: https://github.com/OpenMDAO/openmdao1, following the instructions on the README, not on readthedocs.

Comment: I actually tried that and got the code running (I need openaerostruct for my analysis), thanks anyway for the support